# Why does NullBooleanField in form give a dropdown when rendered in template?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

When I change the form field to CharField, there is no dropdown in the template, BooleanField does not have one either. Why does NullBooleanField get a dropdown(in forms)? What if I dont want a drop down? Is this in built in generic view?

Comment: Then you specify a different widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the HTML specification of the checkboxes they only send value when checked. Quote from the HTML 4 spec:

> When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become successful.

You have no way to figure whether a missing values means it is just missing or is false.

`NullBooleanField` allows you to make that difference but it can not use a checkbox because of the HTML specifications so it has to fall back to a dropdown in order to offer a choice between false value and no value.